# Solve non linear system of equations with rootsolve

Tags: r, optimization, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following nonlinear system of equations with $sigma^2_2$ and $\mu_2$ unknown :
[image]
And here is the code I used in R with the rootSolve library :

```
library(rootSolve)
mu_1 <- -2.931476
sigmasq_1 <- (1.084857)^2
mu_Z <- -6.717234
sigmasq_Z <- 0.104320

model <- function(x) c(F1 = log(((exp(2*mu_1+sigmasq_1)*(exp(sigmasq_1)-1))+(exp(2*x[1]+x[2])*(exp(x[2])-1)))/
                                 ((exp(mu_1+sigmasq_1/2)+exp(x[1]+x[2]/2))^2)+1)-sigmasq_Z, 
                       F2 = log(exp(mu_1+sigmasq_1/2)+exp(x[1]+x[2]/2))-sigmasq_Z/2-mu_Z)
(ss <- multiroot(f = model, start = c(1.5, 0)))
```

However this gives absurd result and the following warning :

> Warning messages:
> 1: In stode(y, times, func, parms = parms, ...) :
> error during factorisation of matrix (dgefa);         singular matrix
> 2: In stode(y, times, func, parms = parms, ...) : steady-state not reached

Comment: Care to tell what are the unknowns.

Comment: My apologies, $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2$ are the unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

The system has an explicit solution.

From the second equation, the argument of the logarithm is a known value, and it can be substituted in the first equation, at the denominator. It also gives us the value of `exp(µ2 + σ2²/2)`, the square of which which we can substitute in the first equation. Finally the first equation can be written `exp(σ2²)-1=a`, which is pretty easy.